# Error while validating inclussion in array Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm having some troubles translating the following sentences to Rails scope:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM permission_activities pa 
JOIN activities a ON pa.activity_id = a.id 
WHERE a.method = :method AND :url ~ a.url_regex AND pa.permission_id IN(:permission_ids)
```

I've come with something like:

```
class PermissionActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permission
  belongs_to :activity

  scope :allowed_access, lambda { |permissions, url, method|
    includes(:activity).where(
      'activity.method = :method AND :url LIKE activity.url_regex
      AND permission_activity.permission_id IN :permissions',
      method: method, url: url, permissions: permissions
    )
  }
end
```

But I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1")
LINE 2:       AND permission_activity.permission_id IN 1,2,3) LIMIT ...
```

Why `permissions` is not being shown as an array? Am I missing something obvious? Or my approach is doomed from it's conception?

Useful information:

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permission_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, through: :permission_activities
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permission_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :permissions, through: :permission_activities
end

class PermissionActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permission
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Comment: `AND permission_activities.permission_id IN ` ? I think you got the table name wrong. That's one then `IN (1,2,3)`, it needs parans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. `~` (in the original query) works with regexes, `LIKE` doesn't.
2. The table names in SQL should be plural, not singular like you have.
3. The `IN` problem that you're asking about.

Fixing the first one is easy: replace the `LIKE` with `~`. Fixing the second is also easy: use the plurals. Fixing the third is also pretty straight forward: `IN` wants a list so add some parentheses around the named placeholder.

Apply those gives you:

```
scope :allowed_access, lambda { |permissions, url, method|
  includes(:activity).where(
    'activities.method = :method AND :url ~ activities.url_regex
    AND permission_activities.permission_id IN (:permissions)',
    method: method, url: url, permissions: permissions
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh, so that was it! Thx a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a string for most of that query:

```
class PermissionActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permission
  belongs_to :activity

  def self.allowed_access(permissions, url, method)
    includes(:activity)
    .where("? ~ activities.url_regex", url)
    .where(
       activities: { 
         method: method
       },
       permission_activities: {
         permission_id: permissions
       } 
     })
  end
end
```

When you chain calls to `where` it will join the conditions with `AND` and the same applies when you pass a hash of conditions.

Do not use scope for multi-line methods - its just a wildly overused syntactic sugar for creating class methods. The documentation is extremely missleading - it does absolutely squat except `singleton_class.define_method ...` and raises if you manage to clobber something. Its just by convention that its used to declare methods that query the db. It makes your code harder to read and hides the method from static analysis.

If you do create multi-line lambdas [use `do ... end` instead of braces](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#lambda-multi-line) just like you would for blocks.

Comment: I would also seriously consider using keyword arguments - there is no logical order to those arguments and they will just be hard to remember.